# getting maximum execution time exceeded in drupal after linking the modules

Tags: drupal

I have installed views, views ui and panel module in drupal, trying to link it with drupal 6 under administrator > site building > modules , but could not do it

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\includes\file.inc on line 1027

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the max_execution_time in your php.ini

Search this file in your xampp folder and restart Apache. Probably it solves your problem.